# Is my Ubuntu LTS EOL?

Tags: 14.04, lts

Lately whenever I run software update I get the message

[image]

suggesting that my version of Ubuntu is EOL. But when I run `lsb_release -a` I get

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Which of these numbers should I pay attention to? `14.04` or `14.04.5`? Because according to the [release wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) support for `14.04.5` runs out on April 2019.

Comment: The message is saying you can upgrade your kernel to the HWE version. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack.

Comment: Press "install" and the supported stack will be installed.

Comment: @Pilot6 No it's doesn't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The message is saying that the hardware enablement stack that you are on is EOL. See the wiki page on [HWE EOL notifications.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HweStackEolNotifications)

This is just one piece of Ubuntu, for those who are running it. It is not the same as the entire OS.

The HWE allows users to take advantage of later kernel improvements and bug fixes while staying on an older LTS version.

You should probably go ahead and upgrade the HWE, otherwise you may miss out on security fixes.

Comment: So the only thing you have to do is press ok to that update? You don't have to install anything yourself?

Comment: @Adam Click Install. If you are on a laptop, it's a good idea to be plugged in.

Comment: Solved I installed the multiarch desktop (not sure what that means)
`sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-xenial:i386 `